# Delphi: Indy search mailbox by skkeyword (thunderbird labels)

Tags: delphi, imap, indy

I trying to get mail labels (setting by Thunderbird) from IMAP. I found some example procedures to search mailbox, but when I try to search by Keywords or Flags, Server disconnects. Below is code that I try to to proceed. IMAP server- Dovecot, Indy version 10

```
IMAPClient.Connect;
if IMAPClient.SelectMailBox('INBOX') then
begin
  SetLength(SearchInfo, 1);
  SearchInfo[0].SearchKey := skkeyword; <<<
  SearchInfo[0].Text := edit1.Text;
  if IMAPClient.SearchMailBox(SearchInfo) then
  begin
    memo1.Lines.add(inttostr(High(IMAPClient.MailBox.SearchResult))+ '-result');
    for I := 0 to High(IMAPClient.MailBox.SearchResult) do
    begin
      MsgObject := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
      try
        if IMAPClient.Retrieve(IMAPClient.MailBox.SearchResult[I], MsgObject) then
        begin
          memo1.Lines.Add(  msgobject.MsgId);
        end;
      finally
        MsgObject.Free;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: do you see the keywords on other PCs or with other mail clients? Are they actually stored server-side?

Comment: When I logged in from other PC, it imports labels, so I think (and documentation confirmed) that labels are stored on server side. On address http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir everything seems logic, so I think that I used wrong Indy method. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a packet sniffer (Wireshark) to examine the communication, and find the last interaction before the server disconnects

Comment: Unless the IMAP server actually supports client-created keywords (as indicated by the `\*` value in the `PERMANENTFLAGS` field of the `SELECT` response), then systems like Dovecot and Thunderbird use their own custom mechanisms for storing labels/keywords off of the server. Even if labels are being stored server-side, `TIdIMAP` has no mechanism in place to actually retrieve them (only search for messages that contain them), since they would be stored as flags, and Indy only supports a small subset of pre-defined flags (unless the IMAP server is Gmail, which `TIdIMAP` has special support for).

Comment: That being said, a single `skKeyword` cannot search for multiple labels at a time. Each label would need its own `skKeyword` entry in the array. However, searching for multiple items at one time performs an `AND` operation, returning only the emails that match ALL of the specified criteria. For multiple labels, it would only find emails that have ALL of the labels. If you need to find emails that contain ANY label but not necessary ALL  of the labels, you will have to call `SearchMailBox()` multiple times, once for each label, and then combine the results together discarding any duplicates.

Comment: As for the disconnect, without more details about the error, and a log from a packet sniffer showing the raw TCP/IMAP activity that is occurring on the socket connection, it is hard to say for sure why the disconnect is occurring.  Under normal conditions, it should not be happening.